# programm for greatest common divisor throw Valueexception

Tags: python, exception

Hello guys i need to write a programm which calculates the greatest common divisor of two numbers.
The programm should throw an exception when 1 of the 2 input numbers are zero. But my code always throws this Exception now :(
Hope you guys can help me :)

```
def ggt (a,b):
    if (b) or (a)==0:
        raise Exception(ValueError)
    else:
        return ggt(int(b), int(a%b))

print (ggt(25,14)
```

Comment: You call your function recursively, but there is no base case, so you always end up with a case where `a % b` is 0.

Comment: How do i make this base case?

Comment: When you use this Euclide algorithm by hand, when do you stop? This condition should be included in your code.

Comment: BTW, `b or a == 0` [_doesn't_ do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: Can you give me an example? When i changed the raise exception to return it worked but i need to do this with this raise Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it can be done like this:

```
def ggt(a, b, first_time=True):
    if a * b == 0 and first_time:
        raise Exception(ValueError)  # the error occurs only if 0 on the first iteration
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return ggt(b, a % b, False)
```